# Rails debug compiled css (SASS) with relative comment path

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I've found at the compiled css assets in my rails application have absolute filesystem paths in the debugging comments. (this is just one example)

```
/* line 6, /Users/<USERNAME>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bundler/gems/refinerycms-1d13007ffe55/core/app/assets/stylesheets/refinery/formatting.scss */
```

So that when a recompilation happens by another team member the file differs by only this

```
/* line 6, /Users/<ANOTHER USER>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bundler/gems/refinerycms-1d13007ffe55/core/app/assets/stylesheets/refinery/formatting.scss */
```

This is obviously silly to have a repository commit for an un-necessary change.
Is there a way to force a relative path for this comment line?

I can see in the gem tests an example file:
sass-3.4.19/test/sass/results/line_numbers.css
which has comments with relative paths

```
/* line 1, ../templates/line_numbers.sass */
```

So I would assume there is some way to achieve this effect easily.

I don't want to turn off comments entirely, I just want to fix the path.

In poking around within the gem code I found something
:css_filename
It looks related to my goal, however I can't see a way to set it within rails as it looks like it applies only to options on the command line.

Thanks

Comment: Generally, compiled assets don't end up in source control because they're compiled on the production environment, after code is deployed. Are you intentionally precompiling them locally?

If so, is there a reason other team members are recompiling css assets that haven't been changed in any other way? It seems to me that they'd only need to recompile if they change the sass source, at which point you would want the compiled assets to be committed anyway because the comment line isn't the only line changing.

Comment: Yes we are precompiling them and then adding them into the git repo. I think the reason for it is because of our test environment. 
Either way the standard procedure we're using is to just run the rake task to rebuild all the assets at once.

Comment: You're running `rails assets:precompile` and you have `config.assets.prefix = "/dev-assets"` in your _config/environments/development.rb_ right? Sorry for these tangential questions, but I feel that files shouldn't be recompiled unless they were changed, even if everyone is constantly running the precompile command. Also what version of rails are you on?

Comment: No we were not using config.assets.prefix
That seems like a useful trick.
I added that in but it did not change the commenting issue.